# Displaying bread crumbs array keyed to number of segments

Tags: pdo

I just converted a query that displays "bread crumbs" style navigation links to PDO:

```
function get_path($dbh,$node,$TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM $TopnavTable WHERE  $TopnavName = ?");
 $stmt->bindValue(1,$node);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
 $row = $stmt->fetch();  
 $path = array_merge(get_path($pdo,$row['Parent'], $TopnavTable, $TopnavName), $path);
 return  $path ;  
}
```

I also figured out how to display the results:

```
$Path2 = explode("/", $path);
$Path2[1] = '<a href="/Topics">'.$Path2[1].'</a>';
$Path2[2] = '<a href="/Topics/'.$Path2[2].'">'.$Path2[2].'</a>';
$Path2[3] = '<span class="navHere"><b>'.$Path2[3].'</b></span>';

echo join( $Path2, ' &gt; ' );
```

But there's a catch. The above works only if I'm working with an array consisting of three segments. For example, I'm viewing the URL MySite/Topics/Washington/Governor, which displays the following bread crumbs trail:

[Topics](/Topics) > [Washington](/Topics/Washington) > Governor

If I view MySite/Washington, it should display...

[Topics](/Topics) > Washington

But I get an error message: Undefined offset: 3

So I'm trying to figure out how to make this work with any number of segments - 2, 3, 6, etc. Regardless of the number of segments, I'd like the last segment to be unlinked. (I'm going to further put it inside a span.) Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$path`  has only 3 members your code works. You have to modify your code to suit if different using array function `count()` & then loop through array.

```
$path ="Topics/Washington/Governor/Trash";
$Path2 = explode("/", $path);
$arrlength=count($Path2);
$html ='<a href="/Topics">'.$Path2[0].'</a> > ';//First Member
for($x=1;$x<$arrlength-1;$x++)  {//Between first & last
     $html .= '<a href="/Topics/'.$Path2[$x].'">'.$Path2[$x].'</a> > ' ;

}
$html .= '<span class="navHere"><b>'.$Path2[$x].'</b></span>';//Last member
echo $html ;
```

**RESULT** for 3

> Topics > Washington > Governor

for 2

> Topics > Washington

Comment: That's perfect, except that Topics and Washington are both linked to /Topics

If I change this line...

    $html .= '<a href="/Topics">'.$Path2[$x].'</a>';

to this...

    $html .= '<a href="/Topics/'.$Path2[$x].'">'.$Path2[$x].'</a>';

...then they're both linked to /Topics/Washington

I'll have to try this with an array with four or five variables. But I'm still doing something wrong.

If it helps, I can remove the first and/or last segment from the array. The first piece will always be <a href="/Topics" title="Topics">Topics</a>.

Comment: The last piece will always be the page URL (or similar value) inside a span. If there are four links between Topics and the last piece, then I just need the code to match the proper link to each piece. The display generally works OK; I just have a hard time getting the proper links, for some reason. Sorry if I made this confusing; I'll play with it some more, and maybe I'll figure it out.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom see modified code. Result 
`<a href="/Topics">Topics</a> > <a href="/Topics/Washington">Washington</a> > <span class="navHere"><b>Governor</b></span>`

Comment: Cool; that works great! The first link in the sequence is /Topics/Topics, rather than Topics/, but I can easily fix that with a str_replace.

I picked up another tip html .= I don't think I've ever seen that before (the dot before the equals sign).

Comment: I use `.=` all the time to build dynamic strings.